# Retrieve Array Clone Method Handle Through a Public Lookup

Tags: java, jvm, invokedynamic

Recently, I attempted to access the `clone` method of an array type through the `java.lang.invoke` library. This proved unsuccessful. The clone method in sample is one such as this:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = a.clone();
```

I wish to create a [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) for the `a.clone()` call. That way the resulting code is similar to:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = findCloneMethod().invoke(a);
```

I have this system set up for every other method invocation. However, the system fails with only this method.

This question pertains to the [`java.lang.invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/package-summary.html) library, **not** the [`java.lang.reflect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) library.

### Problem Description

The following sample code was introduced to show this behavior.

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class Main {

    void test() {
        final MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.lookup();
        final Class<?> refc = int[].class;
        final String name = "clone";

        final MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(Object.class);

        final MethodHandle mh = findVirtual(caller, refc, name, type);

        System.out.println("Lookup: " + caller);
        System.out.println("mh: " + mh);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().test();
    }

    private MethodHandle findVirtual(final MethodHandles.Lookup caller, final Class<?> refc, final String name, final MethodType type) {
        try {
            return caller.findVirtual(refc, name, type);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> Lookup: Main
>
> mh: MethodHandle(Main)Object

---

The output makes sense. The caller, which is from the scope of `Main` only sees the `clone` method in `Main`'s superclass: `Object`. Even though `int[]` is used as the reference class, this method is not visible. This becomes an issue, since if this callsite is used, the JVM attempts to cast `int[]` to `Main`.

By introducing the reference type as `int[]`, one would expect that the `clone` method in type `int[]` is publicly accessible. Therefore, when the documentation suggests:

> The type of the method handle will be that of the method, with the receiver type (usually refc) prepended. [1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#findVirtual-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-)

That the type of `mh` would be `(int[])Object`.

---

### Attempted solution:

Since the Lookup `caller` is interfering by shadowing the proper `clone` method, an attempt was made by using the public lookup:

```
final MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.publicLookup();
```

However, this fails. Simple inspection of the `Object#clone()` signature shows why:

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { ...
```

The method is `protected`. This is not true for array types, as the implementation makes this method publicly available.

An example of this would be trying to access the `Object#equals` method. This is shown with three separate reference classes:

```
final MethodHandles.Lookup caller = MethodHandles.publicLookup();
final Class<?> refc = Object.class;
final String name = "equals";

final MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, Object.class);
```

> Lookup: java.lang.Object/public
>
> mh: MethodHandle(Object,Object)boolean

And then using `Main.class` as the reference class:

```
final Class<?> refc = Main.class;
```

> Lookup: java.lang.Object/public
>
> mh: MethodHandle(Main,Object)boolean

And then using `int[].class` as the reference class:

```
final Class<?> refc = int[].class
```

> Lookup: Main
>
> mh: MethodHandle(int[],Object)boolean

This is the intended behavior, obviously works fluently. In the first case, the reference class was `Object` and it returned the `Object#equals` method handle. In the second, the reference class was `Main` and it returned the `Main#equals` method handle. And finally, the reference class was `int[].class` and it returned the `int[]#equals` method handle.

This parity is *not* maintained with the `int[]#clone` method though. Since the `clone` method is protected, but public for arrays, it can't be found. To me this seems like a bug. The array `clone` method should be made publicly available through the `publicLookup`. The returned method handle type could be: `MethodHandle(Object)Object`.

Once retrieved, the [`MethodHandle#asType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) can then be used to correct the type. In this case, it would be casted to `MethodHandle(int[])Object`.

Without the `Object#clone` method being publicly available, at least for array types, this seems like its not possible.

Furthermore, this seems like the only method where this can possibly happen, as the array types only extend/implement 3 classes: `Object`, `Cloneable` and `Serializable`. The only other method would be `Object#finalize` which is also protected; however, array types do not make this method publicly available. Therefore `clone` is the only method that this fails for.

---

### tl;dr:

The array `clone` method, such as `Object[]#clone()`, is not publicly accessible through the public lookup. This is because `Object#clone` is `protected`; however, array types make this method publicly available. Trying to access the array `clone` through the reference class fails due to this visibility issue. As a result, a `MethodHandle` cannot be generated for this method. However, trying the same techniques on public methods such as `Object#equals` works fine for array types.

---

I would prefer to avoid reflection access, as the methods are there to retrieve it by simply changing the trust level of a lookup.

**Is there any way to generate a `MethodHandle` for the array `clone` method?**

---

Note: I do understand the proper usage of `java.lang.invoke` and I do not intend to use this as a replacement for `java.lang.reflect`.

Comment: What version of java are you using? I get the same problem with `(Main)Object` when using `lookup()`, but it finds the correct method using `publicLookup()`. Actually, that seems to work for 1.8 as well: https://ideone.com/vMmWMr

Comment: @JornVernee I updated my Java version and that seemed to work fine. I was originally running 1.8 (forgot to check minor version). Also, the reference type that was specified was wrongly `Object.class`. The second issue produced a different error though, so I guess it was a combination of both. I'll leave the question up for any answers and if nobody does I'll summarize a community answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug [JDK-8001105](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8001105) in early implementations of JSR 292 where `findVirtual` did not work for array's `clone` method. However, this problem has been fixed a long ago.

So, in recent JDK 8 `findVirtual` works fine for `clone` if called on `publicLookup()`.
You may find a special case for this in [JDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/556b17038b5c/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.java#l1496):

```
        if (Modifier.isProtected(mods) &&
                refKind == REF_invokeVirtual &&
                m.getDeclaringClass() == Object.class &&
                m.getName().equals("clone") &&
                refc.isArray()) {
            // The JVM does this hack also.
            // (See ClassVerifier::verify_invoke_instructions
            // and LinkResolver::check_method_accessability.)
            // Because the JVM does not allow separate methods on array types,
            // there is no separate method for int[].clone.
            // All arrays simply inherit Object.clone.
            // But for access checking logic, we make Object.clone
            // (normally protected) appear to be public.
            // Later on, when the DirectMethodHandle is created,
            // its leading argument will be restricted to the
            // requested array type.
            // N.B. The return type is not adjusted, because
            // that is *not* the bytecode behavior.
            mods ^= Modifier.PROTECTED | Modifier.PUBLIC;
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! So long story short: update your Java version

Comment: Okay..... but why doesn’t it work for other lookup objects, i.e. not being `publicLookup()`? Unlike the OP, I don’t think that “The output makes sense”. In fact, I think that it doesn’t make the slightest sense that the array type gets replaced with the entirely unrelated caller class for other lookup objects.